# The importance for getting an account

Tags: discussion, reputation, badges, stackexchange

Sorry if this question seems stupid. I want to check. What is the importance for getting a high reputation and earning a lot of badges in professional life?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Nobody knows whether or not there will be a miracle in the future --- Joel Spolsky will give you one euro per point you have.

Comment: If that turns out to be true, you're playing a very dangerous game. ;-)

Comment: @AlanMunn::  :-)

Answer (score 24):

There seems to be some consensus on the main Meta site that mentioning participation on StackOverflow is at best a very minor part of one's resume, reserved for the extra-curricular section.  StackOverflow, of course, is a general programming site, and therefore it's possible that participation on the site might be something that an employer might be interested in knowing about.

- [Have you ever used your gained reputation points to get a job or something?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/25453/170190)
- [At what point do you put your SO reputation in your resume?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/58947/170190)

However, there are few, if any employers who would care about TeX knowledge at all, so participation on the TeX.sx, site is likely to have no use to any potential employer.  Additionally, many of us are working academics in various fields and participation in a site like this would have absolutely no bearing on our professional career whatsoever.

Comment: It is possible to use my account to dilever question on opencv or any field in stackexchange?

Comment: @phdstudent If you login to any other StackExchange site with the same OpenID credential, your account should be registered with the same id.  I have no idea about OpenCV.

Comment: Worth noting that on the main site they do link through to a careers site, with the idea that for general programming contributions to SO show that you have potentially-valuable skills. That doesn't really apply to us, as you say :-)

Comment: @AlanMunn: OpenCV is an open library for digital signal processing.

Comment: I would a bit disagree with the last sentence. People are acknowledged for improving the Sage project, for being members of Debian development team, and some of that even to such extent that you link this work to the scientific grants. Therefore I think that one day, active participation in the LaTeX project might be acknowledged the same way. Still, I agree that it's not the activity on this site that would be acknowledged; rather it's package development to help others in your area.

Answer (score 11):

None.

Answer (score 11):

I quietly argue in my department and regularly tell colleagues that significant participation in stackexchange sites should count in faculty reviews as service to the scholarly community. I'm sure @egreg's answers here advance science more than does his mathematics, however deep and interesting that may be.

Answer (score 1):

In the professional life probably none. Although, I think badges as professional rewards in Tex serve to signalling what type of scout you are from Wolf Cub Scout to Scout leader. Until you achieve the status of Robert Baden-Powell.